# Python Can't scrape video src

Tags: javascript, python, python-requests, cloudflare

I'm trying to scrape the site http://kissanime.com/Anime/Fate-stay-night-Unlimited-Blade-Works-TV-2nd-Season/Episode-025?id=111590, but when I try to look for the  tags src, I can't find it. I'm using cfscrape to scrape the site as it is cloudflare protected. I think the src is only displayed through javascript. I currently don't have any sample code.

Comment: You don't code? But you said that you're using cfscrape. Are you asking someone to do this for you? :)

Comment: I meant I don't have any sample code written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There is a  tag by the id of "selectQuality". the value is encoded in base64. Once you decode it will give you the url. Thanks go to roflmuffin.